# Firebase Authentication with multi-factor authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to implement multi-factor authentication on Firebase Authentication? From my research it seems impossible since Firebase authentication has public REST api of which, assumingly, someone knowing API_KEY and user's email/pass could directly sign in to that user's account using

`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API_KEY]`

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "multi-factor athentication" ?  do you want to check something else with username and password?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. No I don't. I want to create one more factor to my authentication. Multi-factor authentication is when a person is granted access to the account only after successfully presenting two or more pieces of evidence (factor), or more than just a password. For example, users need to present correct SMS verification code sent to their phone or correct TOTP (Time-based one time password) from their Google Authenticator after email/password authentication to be able to access their account.

Comment: MFA beta functionality was just merged on the iOS SDK https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/4823

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Update: June 2020

From March 12, 2020, It is now possible to set up multi-factor authentication using SMS as 2nd factor with Firebase for [Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7110_-_march_12_2020) projects but this is a paid service. [This article](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa) shows you how to add SMS multi-factor authentication to your web app.

---

I am quoting from [github firebase repo.](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/285) here.

> Firebase Auth does not support multi-factor authentication. FirebaseUI
>   cannot support this feature until the underlying SDK supports it. For
>   2-factor auth, 2 credentials need to be passed to get a Firebase ID
>   token. Currently, one is enough to get an ID token. You can submit an
>   official request for multi-factor auth with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

However Multi-factor authentication itself works fine with Google account and FirebaseUI if it is enabled from [Google settings](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome).

hope it helps.

Comment: It is now possible to setup multi-factor authentication with Firebase. As far as I can tell they only support SMS based 2 factor, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 10):

Firebase Authentication with multi-factor authentication should soon be available according to [this Google I/O video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGCLPiR_0Lg&feature=youtu.be&t=1432)

Answer (score 4):

Firebase Authentication now supports Multi-Factor Authentication, but it only works for apps using [Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform), which is a paid service.

The logic is:

1. You ask the user to sign in with one of the providers bellow and also ask them to verify their email.

   - Email and password
   - Email link
   - Google
   - Google Play
   - Facebook
   - Twitter
   - GitHub
   - Microsoft
   - Yahoo
   - LinkedIn
2. You ask them for their phone number so you can send them an SMS as the second factor.

In order to enable MFA in your app, you'll need to enable the [Identity Platform API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google-cloud-platform/customer-identity). Note that this will also enable billing on your GCP Project, so you'll need to add credit card details.

Documentation links: [[Web](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa)] [[Android](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/android/mfa)] [[iOS](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/ios/mfa)]

Answer (score 2):

Firebase should be now having Multifactor auth:

- https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7110_-_march_12_2020
- https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa

Answer (score 1):

MFA in Firebase Auth officially landed on July 26, 2022. Here is the blog post that introduces it: https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/07/new-firebase-auth-features

Here's their official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/multi-factor