# How to enable two-factor Authentication on my Firebase Console

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I would like to enable 2FA when I log into my Firebase console. I read that Firebase supports multi-factor authentication for users in Firebase Auth, but I would like to enable it only for logging into my Firebase console to manage my Firebase projects.

Is it possible to enable 2FA only on my Firebase Console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-factor authentication is currently only available in Google's Cloud Identity Platform, not in Firebase Authentication. While the two products are closely related, this is one place where they are different.

To use MFA, you'll have to upgrade to the paid Google Cloud Identity Platform. You'll still be using the Firebase SDKs in your app, so this change doesn't affect the app you send to your users.

For more information, see:

- the GCIP [overview page](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform), which also includes information on pricing
- the GCIP documentation on [multi-factor authentication](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa)
- [Firebase Authentication with multi-factor authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886244/firebase-authentication-with-multi-factor-authentication/52906804)

Comment: Why is this answer talking about Google Auth. The question clearly states Firebase console and therefore admin management there. Is Stackoverflow spinning with bots already over 3 years ago since this answer was written. Maybe just me reading the answers and links like they are towards using auth in the apps not the console.